# Trying to Fetch Full Table and Email Results Maintaining Proper Form

Tags: mysql, perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# DB Account Parameters

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "emegadb";
my $user = "*****";
my $password = "*******";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database;mysql_local_infile=ON";

use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password)
  || die "Unable to connect to database. $DBI::errstr.\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from today1")
  || die "cannot prepare select. $DBI::errstr.\n";
$sth->execute || die "cannot execute select. $DBI::errstr.\n";

while(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref){
   my $daily = join (',', values %$row);

   #print "$daily \n";
   push @table1, "$daily";
}
$sth->finish;

$dbh->disconnect();

MAIL:
use Mail::Sendmail qw(sendmail %mailcfg);

#print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

%mail = (
    To      => 'me@mail.com',
    From    => 'daily_adjust@mail.net',
    Subject => " DAILY ADJUST - DATABASE CAPTURE",
    Message => "DB @table1\n");

$mailcfg{smtp} = [qw(db-ibmv1.mail.net)];

sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;

END:

exit(0);
```

This provides the following results:

```
DB 95,1,15476,1016,289.7,288.8,000000,03:00:00,2015-08-29
286.9,15194,1016,287.7,000000,06:00:00,2015-08-29,100,2
3,95,09:00:00,2015-08-29,000000,15476,289.7,1016,289.0
17379,1016,294.8,294.0,000000,12:00:00,2015-08-29,76,4
77,5,294.5,295.2,17569,1.... ETC
```

What I want is - with column names

```
+------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| id   | date       | time     | percent  | hpa  | min   | max   | dem    | sumadd |
+------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|    1 | 2015-08-29 | 03:00:00 |       95 | 1016 | 288.8 | 289.7 |  15476 | 000000 |
|    2 | 2015-08-29 | 06:00:00 |      100 | 1016 | 286.9 | 287.7 |  15194 | 000000 |
|    3 | 2015-08-29 | 09:00:00 |       95 | 1016 | 289.0 | 289.7 |  15476 | 000000 |
```

Comment: If `values %$row` contains the values, then `keys %$row` contains the keys, which are the column names.  What's the question?

Comment: you might want to keep the hashrefs you get from fetchrow_hashref, with keys pointing to values, if you want both keys and values, instead of pushing only the values into some array which you apparently printed as "RESULTS", then wondering where the keys went.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is how to make a tabular layout using ASCII characters, then what you want is something like [Text::TabularDisplay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::TabularDisplay).

Comment: Yes I guess the question would be better framed as "I need to fetch table data along with the keys (column names) and construct/display the values in a tabular format for email consumption".  I saw the Text::Tab link but I don't fully understand how to combine the email and the query as I am still new at this.

Comment: Instead of selecting `*`, select only the columns you need, in the order you want them. Then use `fetchrow_arrayref` instead of `fetchrow_hashref` and build your table according to the docs I linked to above. Render your table to the message body of your email, and you're all set.